# How do Mirage Islands work?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm trying to find **TM90 Substitute**.  I understand that it is found on one of the **Mirage Islands**.  I also understand that the Mirage Islands that you can visit are random and change based on Streetpass as well as the online passersby that you meet.  However, I don't know how often these change or if there is there is anything to do to get certain islands to appear.

I haven't been looking for very long, but it seems like I keep seeing the same islands over and over, even after trying for a few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_spot):

> Once every 24 hours, a daily *Mirage spot* will appear in Hoenn. You can also encounter more through StreetPass. At the end of a day, all current *Mirage spots* will fade away.
>
> Most *Mirage spots* are marked by a glowing red beacon floating over the location when the player is soaring in the sky on Latios/Latias. This marker is always present for daily Mirage spots.
>
> Many are random and spontaneous, while others may only be found when in possession of certain items or Pokémon.

These **[Conditional Mirage Spots](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_spot#Conditional_Mirage_spots)** are: [Pathless Plain](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pathless_Plain), [Nameless Cavern](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nameless_Cavern), [Fabled Cave](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Fabled_Cave), [Gnarled Den](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Gnarled_Den), [Trackless Forest](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trackless_Forest), [Dimensional Rifts](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_spot#Dimensional_Rifts) and [Storm Clouds](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_spot#Storm_Clouds).

The *TM90 Substitute* you are looking for is on the [Mirage Island located at South of Pacifidlog Town](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mirage_Islands#South_of_Pacifidlog_Town).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of "how do I get my mirage spots to change so I can find the right island I need".

Comment: @Pyritie It seems that you can't, they are random except those I've listed. Anyway OP asked "how often these change or if there is there is anything to do to get certain islands to appear", and I've answered it.